# Python's append() only allows unique items in a list?

Tags: python, data-structures, append

The python documentation implies that duplicate items can exist within a list, and this is supported by the assignmnet: list = ["word1", "word1"]. However, Python's append() doesn't seem to add an item if it's already in the list. Am I missing something here or is this a deliberate attempt at a set() like behaviour?

```
>> d = {}
>> d["word1"] = 1
>> d["word2"] = 2
>> d["word2"] = 3

>> vocab = []
>> for word,freq in d.iteritems():
>> ...  vocab.append(word)

>> for item in vocab:
>> ...  print item
```

returns:

```
word1 
word2
```

Where's the second word2?

Comment: It's helpful if you don't include the `>>` and `...` - this makes it difficult for others to work with your code.

Comment: Sorry, I actually added that in manually after copying my code in from notepad++, as I saw some people do it here to distinguish between code and output. I thought it would help; but won't do it again as you make a good point!

Comment: You may want a [set](http://docs.python.org/release/2.4.4/lib/types-set.html) of tuples rather than a dictionary. This would allow `("word2", 2)` only once, no matter how many times you add it, but will also allow `("word2", 3)` at the same time.

Comment: People don't insert `>>>` and `...` themselves. That comes from the python interactive interpreter. You should use it too -- it helps answer questions like this. Here's an [online version](http://www.trypython.org/), and here's how to [start it up](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/interpreter.html) on your own computer.

Comment: @Steve314 There are multidict implementations out there. It's probably easier to use those rather than embedding such operations in your code as operations on sets.

Comment: @Marcin - but that doesn't help if the point is to have unique pairs of ("string", int), but not unique strings. A multiset (ordered or otherwise) allows duplicate keys - it doesn't force anything to be unique. I assumed the items were being put in a dictionary first for some reason, and the OP had just got confused over what is unique in a dictionary. In the olden days, I'd have suggested a dictionary mapping tuples to dummy values - `d[("word2", 2)] = "dummy"` etc.

Comment: @Steve314 A set of tuples would allow duplicate "keys".

Comment: @Steve314 If you are modelling a relation, one part of the tuple is the key, and the other the value. There can be many tuples containing the same key.

Comment: @Steve314 I'm afraid you've descended into incomprehensibility. We were discussing using sets to model multimaps; when I say "relation" I mean the mathematical abstraction.

Comment: @Steve314 What you wrote has a meaning independent of what you now claim you meant. You said "This would allow ("word2", 2) only once, no matter how many times you add it, but will also allow ("word2", 3) at the same time". That's a description of multimap behaviour, if ever I saw one.

Comment: @Marcin - It was intended (and is) the behaviour of a set of tuples, with the whole tuple as the key, as described. A multimap requires a key *and* data. If you take that as the behaviour of a multimap, either you are lacking data, or you're taking the string as a key and need to explain why (after inserting multiple copies) - the "no matter how many times you add it" condition - there is still only one occurrence of ("word2", 2). Multimaps don't guarantee uniqueness of the (key, data) tuple any more than they guarantee the uniqueness of the key.

Comment: @Steve314 In the context of suggesting that OP replace a map type with a set of pairs, your suggestion amounts to a form of multimap with the additional behaviour that it provides for uniqueness of the `(key, value)` pair. It remains a poor idea to embed such operations in ones code, rather than collecting it into a single (preferably pre-written) class.

Comment: @Marcin - if you need unique (string, integer) tuples (but not unique strings) as my original comment was guessing the OPs intent might be, a set of tuples is the *easy* way precisely because you *don't* need to write any code of your own - you just let the set type do the work. There's no need to invoke multimaps at all - it's just that you've got the idea in your head that the string must be a key, which may even have been the OPs original mistake if you believe my guess. In my original comment, the key (if you call it that) is the whole ("string", integer) tuple.

Comment: @Marcin - put it this way. Even in the OPs question, there is no lookup of items by the string. Once the `d` container is initialised, the only use is to iterate through all the items to build a list. The only reason to consider the string a key is because a dictionary was used, yet the OP clearly wasn't expecting dictionary behaviour.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There *is* no second word2.

```
>>> d = {}
>>> d["word1"] = 1
>>> d["word2"] = 2
>>> d
{'word1': 1, 'word2': 2}
>>> d["word2"] = 3
>>> d
{'word1': 1, 'word2': 3}
```

Dictionaries map a specific key to a specific value.   If you want a single key to correspond to multiple values, typically a list is used, and a defaultdict comes in very handy:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> d["word1"].append(1)
>>> d["word2"].append(2)
>>> d["word2"].append(3)
>>> d
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'word1': [1], 'word2': [2, 3]})
```

Comment: IOW, a dictionary is a map, not a [multimap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimap).

Answer (score 3):

You're putting the words into a dictionary first. Dictionaries do not accept duplicates, so when you enter the same key into the dictionary twice, the second entry overwrites the first. Then, when you iterate over the keys in the dictionary, you get no duplicates.

```
>>> d = {}
>>> d['word1'] = 1
>>> d['word2'] = 2
>>> d['word2'] = 3
>>> print d
{'word1': 1, 'word2': 3}
```

Iterating over a list with duplicates in it works as one would expect:

```
>>> words = ['word1', 'word2', 'word2']
>>> newlist = []
>>> for word in words:
...     newlist.append(word)
... 
>>> newlist
['word1', 'word2', 'word2']
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no second `"word2"`, because `dict`s only have one entry per key. This is the usual behaviour of a hashtable-backed map.

Note that if you just want the keys of a `dict` use `dict.keys()`.

Answer (score 0):

It was never there (unless your example is incorrect). `dict` overwrote it:

```
In [5]: d
Out[5]: {'word1': 1, 'word2': 3}
```

The second `word2` overwrote the first. `dict` keys must be unique.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is not with `append()`, it is that you cannot have duplicate keys in a dictionary, they all must be unique.

This means that the line `d["word2"] = 3` is not adding an additional `"word2"` key, it is overwriting the current value of `d["word2"]`.

Answer (score 0):

Because d is a dictionary, a key may have only one value, so when you modify `d["word2"] = 2` and then `d["word2"] = 3`, you are overwriting the value 2 with 3.

```
>> d = {}
>> d["word1"] = 1
>> d["word2"] = 2
>> d["word2"] = 3

#the fourth line `d["word2"] = 3` only modifies the value of d["word2"].

>> print(d)
{'word1': 1, 'word2': 3}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary maps duplicate keys and overwrites older entry by latest entered entry.

```
>>> d = {}
>>> d["word1"] = 1
>>> d
{'word1': 1}
>>> d["word2"] = 2
>>> d
{'word1': 1, 'word2': 2}
>>> d["word2"] = 3
>>> d
{'word1': 1, 'word2': 3}
```